# Is this a table of tables in PL/SQL (If not what is going on with this code?)

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can someone clarify what the PL/SQL code below is doing?  It looks as if assets_type is a table of base_Asset.  Does that make it a Table of Tables?

I'm having a difficult time visualizing this when it comet to populating the data:

```
assets(v_ref_key)(dbfields(i).field) := rtrim(replace(strbuf_long2,'''',''''''));
```

Is this similar to a two dimensional array?  Does this mean to populate the field column in the assets (temporary) table with an index of v_ref_key?

```
 PROCEDURE LOAD 
 IS

 TYPE dbfields_rec IS RECORD (field         dbfields.field%TYPE,
                         article_title dbfields.title%TYPE,  
                         image_title   dbfields.title%TYPE); 
 TYPE dbfields_type IS TABLE OF dbfields_rec INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
 TYPE base_Asset IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(32);
 TYPE assets_type IS TABLE OF asset_type INDEX BY VARCHAR2(4000);
 dbfields                       dbfields_type;
 assets                  assets_type;
 v_ref_key               assets.ref_key%TYPE;


 -- CLIPPED Populate dbfields array code 
 -- It correctly populates

  FOR i IN 1..dbfields.COUNT LOOP
    BEGIN
        sqlbuf := '(select rtrim(ufld3), ' || dbfields(i).field ||
                  ' as col_label from assetstable ' ||
                        '  where  rtrim(ufld3) = ' || '''' || in_id || '''' || ' )';
       OPEN assets_cur FOR  
            sqlbuf;
       LOOP
          FETCH assets_cur INTO v_ref_key, strbuf_long2; 
          EXIT WHEN assets_cur%NOTFOUND;                 

          IF (trim(strbuf_long2) is not null and dbfields(i).field is not null) THEN
             assets(v_ref_key) (dbfields(i).field)
               := rtrim(replace(strbuf_long2,'''',''''''));
          END IF;
       END LOOP;
       close assets_cur;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END LOAD;
```

Comment: Where is "asset_type" defined?  I don't see it in the declarations.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like the kind of code needed to deal with a EAV-style database schema. "dbfields" etc.

Comment: `assets` is defined as `assets_type`, which is a table of `asset_type`, not `base_Asset`. It looks like the `base_Asset` type isn't used at all.

Answer (score 4):

PL/SQL really only provides one-dimensional arrays - but each element of the array is allowed to be *another* array if you want to make arrays that act like multi-dimensional ones.

Here is an awfully contrived example to illustrate:

```
DECLARE

  TYPE rows_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(4000);

  TYPE spreadsheet_type IS TABLE OF row_type INDEX BY VARCHAR2(4000);

  spreadsheet spreadsheet_type;

BEGIN

  spreadsheet ('row 1') ('column A') := 'XYZ';

END;
```

The first `('row 1')` is the index into the spreadsheet_type array, which would hold all the columns for a particular "row"; and the second `('column A')` is the index into the rows_type array.

The "multi-dimensional" aspect of this implementation isn't perfect, however: while you can work with a whole row if you want, e.g.:

```
my_row rows_type;
...
my_row := spreadsheet ('row 1');
```

you can't pick out a particular column - there's no way to refer to the set of all elements in the rows for a particular index into rows_type. You'd have to do something like make another type and loop through the first array.